# Apache LogLevel

Tags: apache2, error-logging, error-log

I was checking our error.log and it's full ... A lot of (debug/warnings) not needed :

Server 1 :

```
[Tue Apr 26 03:28:14.641442 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12490] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client xx.xx.xx.xx:54849] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Apr 26 03:28:14.641496 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12490] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client xx.xx.xx.xx:54849] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Tue Apr 26 03:28:14.641506 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12490] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client xx.xx.xx.xx:54849] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Tue Apr 26 03:28:14.710134 2016] [headers:debug] [pid 12490] mod_headers.c(845): AH01502: headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
```

Server 2 :

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'newrelic' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Apr 25 06:31:35.756293 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1993] AH00163: Apach              e/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 25 06:31:35.756309 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1993] AH00094: Command line              : '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Apr 26 03:22:14.689539 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1993] AH00169: caugh              t SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  Module 'newrelic' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Apr 26 03:22:15.796372 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3709] AH00163: Apach              e/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 26 03:22:15.796472 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3709] AH00094: Command line              : '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

I modified the apache2.conf for :

```
 LogLevel  error
```

It works on Server2 but not Server1

Restarted the apache2 service and i still see them getting generated in the error.log file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , It was due to another configuration in the sites-available so double configuration.

And It was working on Server2 because they ddnt have that configuration in sites-available .

Comment: What was the problem in the config?